# rsync daemon and permissions

Tags: permissions, daemon, rsync

## Problem

I am confused about `rsync` daemon and permissions. Unfortunately I cannot figure out why I get
`rsync: opendir "/." (in share) failed: Permission denied (13)` and
`rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1650) [generator=3.1.2]`.
Obviously, by searching the web and looking into the `manpage` of `rsync` / `rsyncd.conf` I was not able to solve this issue.

## Setup

Here is my `/etc/rsyncd.conf` owned by `root` with `644` permissions:

```
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
[share]
     comment = data
     path = /path/to/data
     uid = root
     gid = root
     read only = false
     auth users = syncuser
     secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

Note, `/path/to/data` is owned by `root` with `755` permissions (though random `user` or `syncuser` is also not working).
Besides, `/etc/rsyncd.secrets` has `600` permissions and is owned by `root` (I also tried `400` though same issue)

```
syncuser:passwd
```

To start the service (on CentOS7)

```
sudo systemctl start rsyncd
```

A first test as a random `user` on the host machine running the daemon, (also running with `sudo` or as `syncuser` has no effect)

```
rsync user@host::
```

returns `share          data` showing that the configuration is fine?!

However

```
rsync user@host::share
```

leads to the errors mentioned above.

## Tries

Playing with `chmod` (`777`)  and `chown` (`root:root`, random `user:user`, `syncuser:syncuser`) of `/path/to/data` was not changing anything. Moreover I varied `uid` and `gid` to `nobody` but also without success.
Running above `rsync` command on an actual client, from which I want to ultimately copy data to the host is of course also failing.

So what am I missing here? Any hints are of course highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you check SELinux?

If it is enforced, the directory /path/to/data need to be labeled correctly.

For example,
chcon -R -t public_content_t /path/to/data

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about this issue, it was indeed SELinux. As a quick fix, disabling it solved the problem.